# How to rename data.frame's header?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have imported a `.csv file` into R. The data.frame has 126 variables and over 66000 observations. Each variable's (column's) name consists of 4 parts separated by "|".

For example: `infoRecurringCustomer|info|categorical|integer`.

How can I create a function to just select the fist part for all 126 variables before the first "|"? In my example just select "infoRecurringCustomer".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `strsplit` function will do the job.
Here is an example:

```
## df is your dataframe with its variable names following your pattern 
names(df) <- c("infoRecurringCustomer|customer|info|information", "info|categorical|integer|infoRecurringCustomer", "categorical|infoRecurringCustomer|info|information")

## applying strsplit : split on the "|" and get the first element
splitted_var_names <- sapply(names(df), function(x) strsplit(x, "[|]", fixed = TRUE)[[1]][1])
```